# How does ThrowTerminatingError work in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following cmdlet written in C#, it basically just throws an error:

```
[Cmdlet("Use", "Dummy")]
public class UseDummyCmdlet :PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var errorRecord = new ErrorRecord(new Exception("Something Happened"), "SomethingHappened", ErrorCategory.CloseError, null);
        ThrowTerminatingError(errorRecord);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming (I could be wrong), this is the equivalent in PowerShell)

```
Function Use-Dummy()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()

    process 
    {
        $errorRecord = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord -ArgumentList (New-Object System.Exception), 'SomethingHappened', 'NotSpecified', $null
        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($errorRecord) 
    }
}
```

The PowerShell version behaves as expected:

```
Use-Dummy : Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
At line:1 char:10
+ use-dummy <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Use-Dummy], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SomethingHappened,Use-Dummy
```

The C# version however, crashes, with the following information:

```
An exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The pipeline has been stopped.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you expect? C# is not a scripting language - when you hit an unhandled exception, your program crashes.

Comment: I expect identical output. The code does EXACTLY the same thing, just in different languages. Both of them can be executed in PowerShell, I just want to know why the pipeline is suddenly closed when running the C# version and not the PowerShell version.

Comment: How do you use this cmdlet? Is it in a module/snap-in or is it added dynamically? How do you call it? From PowerShell console, ISE, another application? What does "crashes" mean?

Comment: Using it, I just import it via Import-Module. It's a module. You just call it as `Use-Dummy` from PowerShell. It basically crashes (program not responding) and writes the event log with that message.

Comment: It should not be like that. Then it is something else. Can you check (debug/log) that your `ThrowTerminatingError` is really called, i.e. it not crashes before it?

Comment: Checked the stack trace, it's definitely called.

Comment: What PowerShell host you use? I can not reproduce crash with console host or ISE host. `PipelineStoppedException` is [not an exception that you should handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.pipelinestoppedexception.aspx#Anchor_1): *Cmdlets and providers do not have to catch this exception unless they have cleanup operations to perform. They can simply allow this exception to propagate up, and the Windows PowerShell runtime will catch the exception.*

Comment: Cannot repro. I added your cmdlet to my module and called `Use-Dummy` from the PS console. It does not crash. As expected, I get *use-dummy : Something Happened ... At line ...* Tried in PS v2, 4, 5.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it's my environment causing this problem rather than a code problem. Going to try some things, will update later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm, it's an environment problem, and a damn wierd one at that.

Basically if you follow the instructions [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/08/basics-of-writing-a-powershell-module-with-c-part-2-debugging/), then go to debug any binary modules, if you call `ThrowTerminatingError`, it crashes with `PipelineStoppedException`.

Now I need some kind of fix/workaround.

Edit: Found a fix, check 'enable native code debugging' in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the ThrowTerminatingError(errorRecord) into a try block as below.

```
[Cmdlet("Use", "Dummy")]
public class UseDummyCmdlet :PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        var errorRecord = new ErrorRecord(new Exception("Something Happened"), "SomethingHappened", ErrorCategory.CloseError, null);
        try
        { 
             ThrowTerminatingError(errorRecord);
        }
        catch (PipelineStoppedException ex)
        {}
    }
}
```